# How to Intentionally cause Windows Heap Corruption?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, heap-corruption

I'm trying to test the Windows API [HeapSetInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heapsetinformation) with the value ***HeapEnableTerminationOnCorruption*** by attempting to create an Exception code 0xC0000374 which means STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION.

Is there some easy C code to intentionally corrupt the heap?
I've tried the following but does not crash or generate any exception?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    BOOL bResult = HeapSetInformation(NULL, HeapEnableTerminationOnCorruption, NULL, 0);

    HANDLE hHeap = HeapCreate(0, 0, 0);
    LPVOID pBuf = HeapAlloc(hHeap, HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, 1024);

    memset(pBuf, 0x41, 2048);

    HeapFree(hHeap, 0, pBuf);

    return 0;
}
```

**Edited**

Adding the HeapFree() call generated an exception.

```
Faulting application name: memory-map.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x61412573
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.19041.1110, time stamp: 0x8a32a22a
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x000e6c23
Faulting process id: 0x8218
Faulting application start time: 0x01d7a9ba304122bd
Faulting application path: C:\Users\John\source\repos\memory-map\Release\memory-map.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 5b61df71-3ee7-4432-b84b-33251814127d
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I was hoping memset() would trigger WER and terminate the process at that code point. But, instead it was the HeapFree(). I'm not really sure how HeapSetInformation() works.

Comment: So you need to not only corrupt the heap (which your code certainly does do), but corrupt it in a certain specific way that results in that specific error behavior.  Maybe you want to clarify your title.

Comment: I was expecting some kind of heap corruption then HeapSetInformation() would detect it, launch the Windows Error Reporting service and terminate the process. However, it did not.

Comment: I wouldn't expect that this mechanism is magically able to detect every kind of heap corruption.  It presumably does some specific checks (e.g. checking sentinels or checksums at certain locations) which your test may happen to not trigger.

Comment: True. Also I have an inkling that perhaps it's already the default setting for detecting corrupted heaps? Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: To detect overruns at the point of overrun, use Application Verifier to enable PageHeap.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Hey that's a good one. I solved that problem once by swapping the heap functions for wrappers around VirtualAlloc and moving the pointer so the last byte was within 16 bytes of the end of the page (alignment) and the next page marked noaccess. A bit painful but it got the job done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not how to corrupt the heap. You already know how to do that. Your problem is to get the OS to notice so you can verify that it works.

To do that, you need to corrupt the heap and call heap functions until it does. Clearly the easiest way is to allocate a buffer, fill it and well past, then free it. If somehow that doesn't work, try again subtracting 32 from the pointer you got from allocating first.

Comment: Interesting idea. But, should I delete the question as it's not being well received? I don't want to pollute S.O. with ill-defined questions and risk getting banned again. Thanks.

Comment: @vengy: Delete question won't help you.